# ExtJS: Is it possible to display more than one message box at a time?

Tags: javascript, extjs

In my ExtJS application I'm issuing multiple ajax requests. For some of them I display results in MessageBoxes. It often happens that one request comes back, shows a message box and a second later another comes back and shows another message box, which replaces the first one.

I'd prefer the user to have the ability to read the second one, click 'OK' and then read the first one and close it too. Unfortunately Ext.MessageBox is a singleton and so the second MessageBox replaces the first one instead of 'covering' it.

The only solution I see out of this problem is to make a deep copy of Ext.MessageBox. Does anyone have other ideas or see problems with my solution?

I'm using ExtJS 2.3.
Thanks,

Piotr

Comment: You could of course role your own Ext.Window for messages, those will layer accordingly.

Comment: @Lloyd Yeah, this is what I have now - I basically copied a part of the Ext.MessageBox class so that they look more or less the same, but now I have to maintain this logic as well :/ This is why I wanted to just clone Ext.MessageBox - so that I don't have two pieces of logic that do the same thing.

Comment: IIRC MessageBox, in 3 anyhow was a jumble of private functions which makes extending and altering it a pain :(

Comment: @Lloyd You do remember correctly. It's the same in 2.3 :/